# How can I get the image (src) of a Shopify product? (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify-app

I am trying to get the 'src' of the image of a product in Shopify with rails.

I do this in the **controller**:

```
   @products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all)
```

And the data I want to get of each product is its title and image so basically I am doing this in **the view**:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <%= product.title %>
    <%= product.images[0].src %>
<%= end %>
```

This line it's not working: **<%= product.images[0].src %>** because product.images[0] returns this object: **ShopifyAPI::Image:0x007fd6f4092338**

**Product.images:**

> "images"=>[#< ShopifyAPI::Image:0x007fd6f4092338
>   @attributes={"id"=>943579299853, "position"=>1,
>   "created_at"=>"2018-01-16T12:32:53-05:00",
>   "updated_at"=>"2018-01-16T12:32:53-05:00", "width"=>5384,
>   "height"=>3589,
>   "src"=>"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2396/9643/products/playing-guitar-fretboard.jpg?v=1516123973",
>   "variant_ids"=>[]}, @prefix_options={:product_id=>299776016397},
>   @persisted=true>]

How can I get the 'src' value?

Thank you.

> edit::

```
product.images[0].attributes['src']
```

Works perfectly! But it will raise an error if the product doesn't have any images attached to it so first you have to check if your product has an image (if images[0] == null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `<%= product.images[0].attributes['src'] %>`?

Comment: Yes I've tried it, but it raises "ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `attributes' for nil:NilClass):"

Comment: @Gyntonic huh? That's weird. So, `product.images[0]` does return a `ShopifyAPI::Image` object, but `product.images[0].attributes['src']` says that `product.images[0]` is actually a `nil:NilClass` object. Am I right? The idea was that you access the `@attributes` variable, which is a hash, that contains the `'src'` key (according to what you've provided above), and that seems to be what you need.

Comment: Oooh, I've just found the problem. Your answer is correct! Thank you. The problem is that one of my products doesn't have an image, so when I was trying to access to it, obviously, it was null. I just have to make a comprobation before access to it. @Jerry

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking out [this blog](http://www.codeshopify.com/) for a better way to access your product images and their various attributes. They also include sample code. Good luck!